# Apply a different set of styles if backdrop-filter is not supported

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 - Beta 10 to develop a mobile app. And there is a div I want to apply the backdrop-filter blur to.

I know this is not supported in most, but I have a fall back design without the blur for cases where backdrop-filter is not supported.

For versions that does not support backdrop-fiter, I want to use the following css,

```
.panel {
 background-color: #FFF;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

And for versions that do support backdrop-filter, I want to use this,

```
.panel {
 background-color: #FFF;
 opacity: .5;
 backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
 -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

The problem is that the opacity is different for the fallback.

How do I determine and set a different style if one attribute is not supported?

Answer (score 5):

I know you asked the question a while ago, but this might still help you:

```
/* Gets applied everywhere */
 .panel {
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
 }

/* Gets applied if supported only */
@supports ((-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px)) or (backdrop-filter: blur(5px))) {
   .panel {
     background-color: #FFF;
     opacity: .5;
     backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
     -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to try using backdrop filter as your default and do something else if it is not supported. Like this,

```
.thisIsTheClass{
  backdrop-filter: blur( 9px ); /*------ Not supported by Firefox in 2021*/
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 9px );/*------ Not supported by Firefox in 2021*/
}
@supports not ( ( -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(9px) ) or ( backdrop-filter: blur(9px) ) ) {
  /* CSS to provide fallback alternative for Firefox and similar browsers */
  .thisIsTheClass{ background-color: rgba( 188, 188, 188, 0.4 ); }
}
```

Note: Use your own blur and color values.